# div align doesn't work on android textview

Tags: android, alignment

I'm trying to use div align to right in android textview but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
<string name="Avot">
<![CDATA[
<div align="right">
 my text ....
<br />     
</div>     
]]>
</string>
```

Please do not suggest me to work with webview as it doesn't support Hebrew normally
Thank in advance

Comment: webView will support Hebrew if you add the correct encoding to your HTML

Comment: How so? Can you please give an example? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String resources only support `<b>`, `<i>`, and `<u>` tags. `Html.fromHtml()` does not support attributes on `<div>` tags.

Comment: So, what is the alternative to use div in textview.

Comment: @PrAndroid: Parse it yourself and build up your desired results with a `SpannableStringBuilder`. Or, convert the HTML into something that `Html.fromHtml()` or [my CWAC-RichTextUtils parser](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richtextutils) will understand.